# How to fix error 'No signature of method' while using Android ViewBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

**I am trying to use ViewBinding**. To do so I have excluded all the imports from kotlinx.android.synthetic. and added the following code.

```
    buildFeature{
viewBinding true
}
```

**But it is throwing error**: No signature of method: build_7jhh1700vj1t807398gidh9lp.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_7jhh1700vj1t807398gidh9lp$_run_closure1) values: [build_7jhh1700vj1t807398gidh9lp$_run_closure1@6885a244]

Why is that being thrown and what can I do about that?
Here is my full build.gradle(app) code:

Updated build.gradle file; [image: Here]

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aks.navigationsafeargs"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeature {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
buildFeature{
    viewBinding true
}
```

With

```
buildFeatures{
    viewBinding true
}
```

It is `buildFeatures`. There is 's' missing.

Comment: Now I am getting this error : [databinding] {"msg":"Found \u003clayout\u003e but data binding is not enabled.\n\nAdd buildFeatures.dataBinding \u003d true to your build.gradle to enable it.","file":"C:\\Users\\akash\\AndroidStudioProjects\\NavigationSafeArgs\\app\\src\\main\\res\\layout\\fragment_home.xml","pos":[]}

Comment: Have you added `<layout>` tag to your layout files? If you need to bind data as well using this tag, then set `dataBinding true`. Else remove those tags from XML layout files

Comment: yes, I have added the <layout> tag. And even after enabling dataBinding in buildFeatures, It is throwing the same error.

Comment: Did you sync after adding it? Please share the updated `build.gradle`

Comment: Yes, @VarshaKulkarni I have synchronized the Gradle file. I have already shared my Gradle file in the question itself. Nothing I have changed even after adding code for dataBinding.

Comment: You are supposed to set `dataBinding true`. That is change you need to make in `build.gradle` for `<layout>` tags to be working.  It is not done in the gradle file shared above.

Comment: I have updated the question with an Image.

Comment: Hey! did you get it working. Sorry somehow missed this one.

Comment: No, I could not.

Comment: Do you have the repo on Github? I can have a look.